# Python Asynio: Unable to run parallel asynio couroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using Asyncio to process 58 cameras in parallel. First I am trying to load all the images from opencv python's imread method. I tried both, the normal way (sequentially) and with Asynio but they both takes almost the same amount of time.

```
 async def loadImage(i):
    return base64.b64encode(cv2.imread(my_local_path)).decode('utf-8')

def loadImageSync(i):
    return base64.b64encode(cv2.imread("frames_set/Kamera {}.jpg".format(i))).decode('utf-8')
```

**Main Func**

```
async def main():

        starttime_lmSync = time.time()
        lm = [loadImageSync(i) for i in range(1,59)]
        print("Loading Images {}".format(time.time() - starttime_lmSync))

        starttime_lm = time.time()
        lm = [loadImage(i) for i in range(1,59)]
        rawImage = await asyncio.gather(*lm)
        print("Loading Images aSync {}".format(time.time() - starttime_lm))
```

Output:

> Loading Images 1.320235013961792
>
> Loading Images aSync 1.3253769874572754

What am i doing wrong? Or is this expected?

After loading a batch of images i want to decode them and convert it into a numpy array. For a single image it takes ~0.02 seconds, so in order to process all of them in parrallel i am using asynio

```
async def process_image(im):
    return  np.asarray(np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(im), np.uint8),dtype=np.float32).reshape((1080,1920,3))

starttime_process = time.time()
futures = [process_image(img_b64) for img_b64 in rawImage]
res = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
print("total time taken {}".format(time.time() - starttime_process))
```

output

> total time taken 1.2220990657806396

Again, The time it takes is nearly equal to that of sequential calling. Is there something which i am missing?

Python version: 3.7
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Hey, I hope you get a more thorough answer from someone else --> but i think you will only see a significant improvement in speed using asyncio in code that does a lot of waiting. From what I can see you code is just processing data which is why you are not seeing significant performance difference.

Comment: Thanks @ilamaaa. Makes sense. So is there a way in python to speed up things without using asynio. I tried threading as well but go nearly the same result

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html I have been meaning to test these guys out properly and solidify my understanding of the strengths and weaknesses for ages but have never really got around to it. Would be interested to see your results using multiple processes.

Comment: I tried POOL, Threadpool, processes, but there is no change in time :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `loadImage` function is not a co-operative coroutine, so even if you've used `asyncio.gather` to spawn them in parallel, they will block the thread.

You need to delegate the tasks to different threads by using a thread pool so that each coroutine is run in separate thread without blocking each other.

Here's one approach with a `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60)
```

As most threads will be I/O bound, spawning 60 should not be a huge problem.

Now, you can modify your `loadImage` like:

```
async def loadImage(i, event_loop, executor):
    return base64.b64encode(await event_loop.run_in_executor(executor, cv2.imread, my_local_path)).decode('utf-8')
```

The above should make `loadImage` a (co-operative) coroutine, and you should see speed improvements on I/O bound tasks.

*(There could be some speed penalty having to spawn so many threads, and allocating resources).*

Comment: Thanks. 
However, in my case i have to listen of those 60 streams continuously, before using asyncio i was using threads, but after reading your comment, i realised that this implementation will also use threads. So I have some questions, is asyncio worth it in my case? Will i get some benifits in moving from python threads to asyncio? Can you suggest me a better way for my use case? @heemayl

Comment: @shahidammer My rule of thumb is: if the tasks are I/O bound, go for `async` and if the tasks are CPU bound, go for `multiprocessing`.

Comment: In my use case, those 60 workers will get the live streams 24/7 (in an infinite loop). Considering this, will i get any benefits with asyncio over threading in terms of resources?

Comment: @shahidammer `asyncio` tries to do co-operative multitasking in a *single thread*. In this case, you need to spawn a thread pool to push off the tasks to the pool to do the workings as your functions are not inherently co-operative co-routines. But as the event loop will do the orchestration, i think you will definitely get benefits over plain threading.

Comment: @shahidammer Glad i could help. I want to emphasize that you should always do benchmarks before settling into a decision as far as performance is concerned.